# Cordova app opens itself an external URL at startup

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am developing a hybrid application with Cordova. I produced the APK file that I installed on Android 5.0 (Samsung Galaxy A7). But when the application starts, after the splashscreen it tries to open an external link. If I refuse, I stay in the app. If I agree to open this external link in the browser of my smartphone (Opera Mini), it opens the page: http://searchguide.level3.com/search/?q=file%3A///android_asset/www/index.html&r=&t=0
In fact, it does on the site "Searchguide.level3.com" search on: "file:///assets_android/www/index.html"
How to avoid this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share some code? And can you explain what the intended behaviour is? Do you want this link to open? Or is it unintentional?

Comment: Hi, thank you for being interested in my question. I don't know what was causing the problem but I solved it by creating another Cordova project and copying the www folder inside.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was causing the problem but I solved it by creating another Cordova project and copying the www folder inside.